# Add a class only if the element requires scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm looking to add a class to an element but only if the content requires the user to scroll.

The element in question responds to screen size, and so it will only require the user to scroll on smaller screen sizes. I'd like to add different styles to the element in that case only and not when the content fits without scrolling.

I'm unsure how to do this but I'm confident there will be a js/jquery solution out there somewhere!

Comment: Are you simply looking to detect if the element has scrollbars?

Comment: Why not just use the css media queries?css media queries are best for these kind of things

Answer (score 1):

For a given element let's say with an id "MyId" you can do this :

```
if ( $('#MyId')[0].scrollHeight > $('#MyId').innerHeight() )
{
    $('#MyId').addClass('myClass');
}
```

Explanation :

- **scrollHeight**

this is the  height of an element's content including what's not visible due to overflow.

- **innerHeight**

this is the actual height of the element content, including top and bottom padding, and taking into account horizontal overflow.

as opposed to

- **clientHeight**

which is the same but doesn't take into account horizontal overflow.

Comment: `scrollHeight` is a native javascript feature, not jQuery.

Comment: you're right forgot the [0]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Basically you check if element's actual height is bigger than just it's visible height.

```
if($(element).innerHeight() < $(element)[0].scrollHeight) {
    $(element).addClass('scrollable-div');
}
```

Comment: this will not work if the element has padding

Comment: this will now work except it's exactly the same as my answer :D

Comment: Your point being? You answered about 10 seconds before me, and you edited your answer afterwards as well. Plus you don't have any explanation on how it works. You should always explain how your answer works in order for it to bring value to future readers as well as OP.

Comment: I didn't mean it in a bad way, you did explain it better, I was just being cheeky, no offense! I upvoted you for not calling me a git :)

Comment: No worries, upvoted your answer too, just edit in some quick explanation and OP should definitely choose your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `.scroll` function, it won't function if you don't scroll.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 0) {
        // do something
    }

});
```